# How to multiply the coefficients for each group and then calculate the percentage of the original value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset like the toy dataset below:

```
   s=structure(list(month_id = c(202306L, 202305L, 202307L, 202305L, 
202306L, 202307L), MDM_Key = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), sale_count = c(NA, 
19161L, NA, 17726L, NA, NA), iek_max_discount = c(0.5356, 0.5256, 
0.5456, 0.559, 0.569, 0.589)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

and another dataset with coefficients

```
cf=structure(list(MDM_Key = 1:2, ML.coef = c(1.46, 1.67)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

`iek_max_discount` is a percentage value, that is, not 0.5356, but 53.56

I need  each coefficient of each `mdm_key`(group variable, from `cf`)  multiply by the corresponding `iek_max_discount`(to the corresponding `mdm_key`)  value from the last current month (from `s` dataset).

For example, today the current month is May. This means that for `mdm_key =1`, we take the coefficient 1.46 and multiply by the value of June (`month_id=202306` and `1,46*53,56=78`).

The resulting value is also a percentage; now, let's calculate what proportion is 78% of the initial value`sale_count` (it is also presented only for the current month). `19161/100*78=14945`.

Then the result must be added to 19161 and sum is inserted into  the month of June.

Similarly, we do this for the month of July (`month_id=202307`); multiply by the coefficient `1,46*54,56=79`. Calculate proportion: `19161/100*79=15137`

We add the resulting value to 19161 and insert the result into the  month of July.

For example desired output for mdm_key=1

```
month_id    MDM_Key sale_count  iek_max_discount    percent prop    final
202306           1               0,5356                  78 14945   34106
202305           1  19161        0,5256         
202307           1               0,5456                  79 15137   34298
```

After the same procedure we do for mdm_key=2 (or any other mdm_key, if any.)

What is the best and easiest way to do such a sequence of arithmetic operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is always a first month that has a *sale_count* per *MDM_Key*

```
library(dplyr)

merge(s, cf) %>% 
  arrange(MDM_Key, month_id) %>% 
  mutate(ML.coef = if_else(!is.na(sale_count), NA, ML.coef), 
         percent = iek_max_discount * ML.coef * 100, 
         prop = (percent / 100) * sale_count[1], 
         final = sale_count[1] + prop, .by = MDM_Key)
  MDM_Key month_id sale_count iek_max_discount ML.coef percent     prop
1       1   202305      19161           0.5256      NA      NA       NA
2       1   202306         NA           0.5356    1.46 78.1976 14983.44
3       1   202307         NA           0.5456    1.46 79.6576 15263.19
4       2   202305      17726           0.5590      NA      NA       NA
5       2   202306         NA           0.5690    1.67 95.0230 16843.78
6       2   202307         NA           0.5890    1.67 98.3630 17435.83
     final
1       NA
2 34144.44
3 34424.19
4       NA
5 34569.78
6 35161.83
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)

cur_month <- as.integer(202305)

s %>% 
  right_join(cf, by = "MDM_Key") %>% 
  mutate(percent = floor(if_else(month_id == cur_month, 
                           NA, ML.coef * iek_max_discount * 100)),
         prop = floor(percent * sale_count[month_id == cur_month]/100),
         final = sale_count[month_id == cur_month] + prop, 
         .by = MDM_Key)
```

```
#>   month_id MDM_Key sale_count iek_max_discount ML.coef percent  prop final
#> 1   202306       1         NA           0.5356    1.46      78 14945 34106
#> 2   202305       1      19161           0.5256    1.46      NA    NA    NA
#> 3   202307       1         NA           0.5456    1.46      79 15137 34298
#> 4   202305       2      17726           0.5590    1.67      NA    NA    NA
#> 5   202306       2         NA           0.5690    1.67      95 16839 34565
#> 6   202307       2         NA           0.5890    1.67      98 17371 35097
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a little hard to understand what you were trying to do. Here is my best guess:

```
# merge them together to have the key in the same row
scf <- merge(s, cf, by = "MDM_Key")

# split into lists by each unique MDM_Key
s_by_key <- split(scf, s$MDM_Key)

# loop through each element of the list
for(i in 1:length(s_by_key)){

  # trunc to remove the decimals
  s_by_key[[i]]$percent <- trunc(s_by_key[[i]]$iek_max_discount *  s_by_key[[i]]$ML.coef * 100)
  
  # get the most recent sales month
  months_with_sales <- which(!is.na(s_by_key[[i]]$sale_count))
  latest_month_with_sales <- which.max(s_by_key[[i]]$month_id[months_with_sales])
  
  last_sales <- s_by_key[[i]][latest_month_with_sales, "sale_count"]
  s_by_key[[i]]$prop <- trunc(last_sales / 100 * s_by_key[[i]]$percent)
  s_by_key[[i]]$final <- last_sales + s_by_key[[i]]$prop
  
  # and set those rows to NA to be like the desired output
  s_by_key[[i]][latest_month_with_sales, c("percent","prop","final")] <- NA
  
}

output <- do.call(rbind, s_by_key)
output
#    MDM_Key month_id sale_count iek_max_discount ML.coef percent  prop final
#1.1       1   202306         NA           0.5356    1.46      78 14945 34106
#1.2       1   202305      19161           0.5256    1.46      NA    NA    NA
#1.3       1   202307         NA           0.5456    1.46      79 15137 34298
#2.4       2   202305      17726           0.5590    1.67      NA    NA    NA
#2.5       2   202306         NA           0.5690    1.67      95 16839 34565
#2.6       2   202307         NA           0.5890    1.67      98 17371 35097
```

Comment: Why do you need to split the data after merge? read more about `ave` and `by` in `base`.

Comment: @M-- I have often found (especially on stack questions where we don't know what edge cases the data really has) that it's easier to inspect where & why a looped function/algo will fail within an actual for loop. It's easier to line-by-line test and fix it up. I've never found the by function more helpful in explaining code than an actual loop. But it looks like I'll be reading more.